# Graph of the function $[\frac{1}{x}]$

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm interested in the graph of the function $[\frac{1}{x}]$. may seems simple, also I graphed it myself. But there is difference between my solution and the manual solution.
Here is the solution of the solution manual:
[image]
But I think it's wrong about $x<-1$.
any response appreciated.

Comment: If by $[x]$ you mean the floor function, the book is wrong and all the lines for $x \lt 0$ should move down $1$.  If you mean integer part, see how it is defined for negative $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If by $\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$ you mean "the integer part of $x$", then the plot is correct.

Note that if $x < -1$, then $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| < 1$, so $\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$ has integer part $0$.

Edit: This answer is based on the following convention: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html

Comment: if $x=-1.5 \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{x} = -\frac{2}{3} \Longrightarrow -1<\frac{1}{x}<0 \Longrightarrow [\frac{1}{x}]=-1$

Comment: The integer part of $-\frac23$ is $0$.

Comment: Note that the most common convention is for $\lceil x\rceil$ to mean "ceiling of $x$", $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to mean "floor of $x$", and $\left[ x\right]$ to mean "integer part of $x$." This nomenclature is by no means universal, however, and different individuals have different intentions for ceiling/floor as to whether it rounds in a signed sense, or in an absolute sense.

Comment: In the "caculus, spivak, 3rd ED", in the heading of problem 17 chapter 4, he says:" The symbol $[x]$ denotes the largest integer which is $\leq x$. Thus, $[2.1] =[2]=2$ and $[-0.9]=[-1]=-1$ ..." is it true?

Comment: It is true within his book, but maybe not other books. We must also be very clear what is meant by "largest integer", because of course, $0 \ge -1$, but $|0| \le |-1|$.

Comment: Better use the notation in @Arkamis' comment, floor/ceiling are mnemonic. "Integer part" is ill-defined, better avoid it.

Comment: So could we say his answer in his solution manual is wrong, considering his definition in his text?

Comment: @shapoor What problem/page is this on? I'll check my 4th ed copy when I get home to see if it persists or was fixed.

Comment: page 72, problem 17, chapter 4

Comment: @Arkamis!  The integer part of $1/2$ is $-1$, not $0$.

Comment: @user72694 Some people explicitly define the integer part of a number as the thing that comes before the decimal point! $[-0.5]$ can be either $0$ or $-1$ depending on your convention.

Answer (score 1):

When $x\to-\infty$ the reciprocal $1/x$ is strictly between $-1$ and $0$ and therefore the integer part (the largest integer smaller than $x$) is $-1$.  The graph you reproduced shows the value $0$ for large negative $x$, which is incorrect.

Comment: From Mathworld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html
"The integer part function satisfies $\textrm{int}(-x) = -\textrm{int}(x)$." So $\textrm{int}(-0.5) = -\textrm{int}(0.5) = -0 =0$.

Comment: As my other comments have indicated, this is far from a universal convention, however!

Comment: @Arkamis, as mathworld points out, this is the case " In many computer languages". I have never seen a math textbook using such a convention. Notice that the OP used the standard notation found in math books rather than mathworld's "int(.)"